# Cakephp: Access data in add function

Tags: cakephp

I'm using the CakePHP blog example:

```
function add() {        
if (!empty($this->data)) {           
 if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->data)) {                
 $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');               
  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));            
  }        
}}
```

I want to modify it in a way that the user is redirected to the post after adding it:

But this doesn't work:

```
  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Post->id)));
```

What is the correct way to read the model's data after creation?

Comment: It might be because you are using `saveAll()`. Try with `save()` and find out what's in `$this->Post->id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As metrobalderas says, break up the save.

```
if ($this->Post->save($this->data))
{
  unset($this->data['Post']; // So that we don't add another
  $this->Post->saveAll($this->data);
  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->Post->id)));
}
```

Comment: $this->saveAll($this->data); Doesn't work: Call to undefined method CarsController::saveAll()

Comment: he meant: $this->Model->saveAll, and in this case $this->Post->saveAll (logically^^)

Comment: Sorry. Corrected (assuming we're in PostsController).